# Eclipse E4: E4 Dev Tools Official Download Site. And why Aren't They Included?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

Is there an Official E4 (Eclipse) download site for the E4 Dev Tools? I keep using the Vogella download site and that seems to be failsafe, but is there no way of getting to those tools through the Eclipse Foundation site?

Also, why aren't those tools included in the latest versions of the Eclipse For RCP/RAP IDE. I've downloaded both the latest Luna and now even the unofficial Mars versions of the Eclipse IDE, and they aren't included. Why on earth not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is not included because it is a sort of soft roll-out of new and developing feature sets.  Anyways, below is the official build download page and the wiki detailing releases and happenings.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4

http://download.eclipse.org/e4/downloads/